# How can I get a 'quoted form of' using a variable?

Tags: macos, shell, automation, applescript

I have been working to create a script that iterates over files and is able to get the 'Keywords' metadata from the spotlight metadata. In getting help from others on stackoverflow, I have been able to get the metadata, but I cannot iterate over the files.

```
tell application "Finder"
set sourceFolder to folder POSIX file "/Users/jdavidson/Desktop/Upload/Birds and Butterflies/HighRes/"
set theFiles to files of sourceFolder
set inputPath to "/Users/jdavidson/Desktop/Upload/Birds and Butterflies/"

end tell

repeat with afile in theFiles
set filename to name of afile
set fname to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in filename) - 1) of filename
set pathVAR1 to "/Users/jdavidson/Desktop/Upload/Birds and Butterflies/HighRes/"
set pathVAR2 to pathVAR1 & filename
--set pathVAR3 to "\"" & pathVAR2 & "\""
set pathVAR3 to quoted form of pathVAR2

display dialog pathVAR3

set myvar to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemKeywords " & pathVAR3

--Substring's the data to between "(" and ")"--
--set var1 to var1 + 1
set var2 to ((offset of ")" in myvar) - 1)
--set var2 to var2 - 1
set myKeywords to ((characters var1 thru var2 of myvar) as string)
display dialog myKeywords

end repeat
```

The code the does work and doesn't error out is as follows:

```
set myvar to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemKeywords " & quoted form of "/Users/jdavidson/Desktop/Upload/Birds and Butterflies/To Process/Floral/RF78-3.tif"
set var1 to ((offset of "(" in myvar) + 1)
--set var1 to var1 + 1
set var2 to ((offset of ")" in myvar) - 1)
--set var2 to var2 - 1
set myKeywords to ((characters var1 thru var2 of myvar) as string)
display dialog myKeywords
```

The issue is being able to pass a variable to shell in 'quoted form of'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to get the files in the folder as `alias list` and get the POSIX paths from the aliases.

`path to desktop as text` is the (HFS) path to the desktop of the current user

```
set sourceFolder to (path to desktop as text) & "Upload:Birds and Butterflies:HighRes:"
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files of folder sourceFolder as alias list
end tell

repeat with aFile in theFiles
    set myvar to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemKeywords " & quoted form of POSIX path of aFile
    --- ...
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote everything and was able to get it work with the below code:

```
    set pathVAR1 to "/Users/johndavidson/Desktop/Upload/Temp/HighRes/"

    set pathVAR2 to pathVAR1 & filename

    set myvar to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemKeywords " & quoted form of pathVAR2

    set var1 to ((offset of "(" in myvar) + 1)

    set var2 to ((length of myvar) - 1)

    set myKeywords to ((characters var1 thru var2 of myvar) as string)
```